# NDK android_app gets APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW without a window?

Tags: android-ndk, android-lifecycle, native-activity

My [NDK-based](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/concepts) Android App is using [android_native_glue.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/gingerbread/ndk/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c) that defines the android_app structure.

Member of this structure is android_app.window and the source-code comments have this to said about it:

```
// When non-NULL, this is the window surface that the app can draw in.
ANativeWindow* window;
```

Judging from my Google Play Developer Console crash reports, I see that there are a lot of crashes where this window pointer is nil, when I am handling a APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW command.

What is the reason for a [NativeActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity) getting APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW without a window set?

What is the best response to handle a nil window to your native app?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing.
This makes APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW downright useless.